# How to give k identical objects to n different people such that each of them gets odd number of these objects?

Tags: combinatorics

How to give k identical objects to n different people such that each of them gets odd number of these objects? I don’t know how to include odd number thing.

Comment: Show your work: can you find the number of way to distribute the objects without the restriction?

Comment: HINT Given each person $1$ ... and hand out the rest in pairs. How many such pairs are there?

Comment: If n is number of peopl and k number of objects then (k+n-1) choose (n-1)

Comment: You may be asking about "partitions into odd parts," but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $x_i$ be the number of objects given to person $i$, you are counting soluitions to the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n = k,
$$
subject to the constraint that each $x_i$ is an odd positive integer. Letting $y_i=(x_i-1)/2$, this is equivalent to counting nonnegative integer solutions to
$$
y_1+y_2+\dots+y_n=(k-n)/2,
$$ 
which can be done with stars and bars.

Comment: How can I use stars and bars then?

Comment: @Michael you already gave the solution in your response to my comment: $\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}$ becomes $\binom{(k-n)/2+n-1}{n-1}$

Comment: @DanielMathias Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Now I got it.